# IOS-UIAutomation: An script running issue.(Turning off screen / Sleep system on MAC)

Tags: macos, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'd like to run some scripts by instruments uiautomation to test my iOS APP during the night. But it seems like the progress will be stop when I turn off Mac screen or let system sleep.

I am sure that it works fine on my friend's Mac...

Any ideas? Is that a system or instruments setting issue? How can I do to keep test runing while mac screen is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to computer preferences, click on energy saver, and make sure all sliders are set to "never", on battery and on power adapter. This will keep your computer awake and so as the instruments uiautomation.

[image]

Then once instruments is running, press on:

> ctrl + shift + eject

[image]

That will dim the screen without stopping instruments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That' s true it will keep my computer awake. But the question is that when I turn off the SCREEN(system still awake), the instruments progress stopped unexpectedly...

Comment: What type of Mac machine do you have @Nickee

Comment: OS X Yosemite
version 10.10.5
iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012)
Processor 2.7GHz Intel Core i5
Memory 8G 1600 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk Macintosh SSD
Graphics NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M 512MB

Comment: It make sense!! Just using your way 'ctrl + shift + eject' isntead of my way 'command + option + eject'... ahaaaa~ A new discovery is that when I used 'command + option + eject', instruments printed "Connection peer refused channel request for 'com.apple.instruments.server.services.wireless'..." on console.

Comment: do you have WeChat? Can you kindly add me for more communications? (Account: Vp_555)

Comment: @Nickee Great! Can you please mark my answer as the correct answer + voting up on it? Big thanks.

Comment: For about iOS and instruments?